# descargar y tratar imagen desde servidor remoto

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fpdf

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación, la cual de una BD obtengo la URL de una imagen y debo crear un PDF que contenga esa imagen. Para el PDF estoy usando FPDF, consigo la ruta de la BD y monto la imagen, pero el problema es para que la reconozca FPDF, ya que esa imagen puede estar en la BD o no, si no está en un input introduzco la URL y al cambiar el foco con JS obtengo su valor ya ya la trato.

El problema que tengo es con el primer caso, que la imagen esté en la BD, debo descargar la imagen de un servidor de un distribuidor, estoy usando para ello Curl, pero a la hora de mostrar la imagen me devuelve "parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible" que está corrupta la imagen. Adjunto mi código actual a ver si alguien me puede iluminar en esta cuestión, descargarla la descargo, pero no correctamente.

posteriormente debo indicar a FPDF la ruta local donde se encuentra la imagen, eso me va a dar igual, porque siempre voy a sobreescribir esa imagen y la ruta no va a cambiar... O si hay una solución más instantanea, desde la ruta que obtengo de la BD, que directamente es la imagen, pues me ahorro todos los demás pasos, pero si hago eso, FPDF no reconoce la imagen y no genera el PDF.

Gracias y un saludo

Código actual

```
//comprobamos que imagen es la que viaja
$imagen = "";


if($_POST["imagenProductoBD"] != ""){
    $imagen = $_POST["imagenProductoBD"];

    $output_filename = 'imagen.jpg';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imagen);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // <-- don't forget this
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // <-- and this
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);

}else{
    $imagen = $_POST["imagenProducto"];
}

// CREAMOS el PDF
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
// PRIMER DIGITO ES LA POSICIÓN A LA IZQUIERDA, SEGUNDO ALTURA, TERCERO ANCHURA IMAGEN, CUARTO ALTURA IMAGEN
//$pdf->Image('../vistas/img/logoIntegra.png',10 ,22, 80, 38, 'png');
$pdf->Nombre();
$pdf->escribeNombre();
$pdf->Apellidos();
$pdf->escribeApellidos();
$pdf->Telefono();
$pdf->escribeTelefono();
$pdf->Dni();
$pdf->escribeDni();
$pdf->Fecha();
$pdf->escribeFecha();
$pdf->Articulo();
$pdf->escribeArticulo();
$pdf->Precio();
$pdf->escribePrecio();


$pdf->Image($imagen, 80, 130, 40, 38, 'jpg');
$pdf->Detalles();
$pdf->escribeDetalles();


$pdf->Output('ofertaEmseel.pdf','F');
```

**EDITADO PARA MOSTAR URL**

```
https://www.aseuropa.com/images/uploads/producto/3042/supergrass_multipanel_8_en_1_black.jpg
```

**PROBLEMA EN CONSOLA**

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(https://www.aseuropa.com/images/uploads/producto/3042/supergrass_multipanel_8_en_1_black.jpg
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php</b> on line <b>161</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  getimagesize(): Read error! in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php</b> on line <b>1237</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: imagen.jpg in C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php:271
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(1239): FPDF-&gt;Error('Missing or inco...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php(885): FPDF-&gt;_parsejpg('imagen.jpg')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\generarOfertaPDFemseel.php(190): FPDF-&gt;Image('imagen.jpg', 80, 130, 40, 38, 'jpg')
#3 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\control2\controladores\fpdf\fpdf.php</b> on line <b>271</b><br />
```

Comment: Puedes indicar un ejemplo de valor de `$imagen`? Debe ser una URL completa para que se pueda descargar. Si no requiere algun parametro o encabezado adicional como autentificacion puedes simplificar usando file_get_contents() para descargarla y file_put_contents() para escribirla en archivo sin problemas de codificacion.

Comment: Si aun asi te da error, revisa el contenido binario del archivo puede que te estê entregando un mensaje de error, estar vacio, o pueda redirigirte a otra direccion. Prueba la URL directamente en un browser para ver si te lleva a la imagen o a otra cosa

Comment: @F.Igor Gracias por tu respuesta, la cadena de la URL la pongo en la descripción de mi problema

Comment: @F.Igor la url lleva a una imagen

Comment: @F.Igor como se puede observar es una URL bien formada, la que debería de traer la imagen, de echo se puede ver que trae una imagen

Comment: Cuando utilizas `$imagen = $_POST["imagenProducto"]`, esta es una ruta local, los datos binarios de la imagen o tambien una URL?

Comment: @F.Igor es una ruta que está almacenada en la BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en que usas la variable `$imagen` como la *ruta local del archivo*, por lo que deberias hacer algunos ajustes en la parte que descarga la imagen:

```
if($_POST["imagenProductoBD"] != ""){
    $imagen_url = $_POST["imagenProductoBD"];

    $imagen = 'imagen.jpg';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imagen_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // <-- don't forget this
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // <-- and this
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fp = fopen($imagen, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);

}else{
    $imagen = $_POST["imagenProducto"];
}
```

Basicamente cuando descargas la imagen, la variable $imagen queda con la URL de descarga, no con el archivo local. Por lo que es mejor conservar la variable `$imagen` para almacenar la ruta local en ese caso, y usar otra variable para la URL.

Si no hay mayores problemas para descargar puedes simplificar el codigo usando las funciones de lectura/escritura `file_get_contents()` y `file_put_contents()`:

```
if($_POST["imagenProductoBD"] != ""){
    $imagen_url = $_POST["imagenProductoBD"];

    $imagen = 'imagen.jpg';

    $result=file_get_contents($imagen_url);
    file_put_contents($imagen, $result);

}else{
    $imagen = $_POST["imagenProducto"];
}
```

Si el error que se produce es el siguiente:

```
file_get_contents(https://www.aseuropa.com/images/uploads/producto/3042/supergrass_multipanel_8_en_1_black.jpg
): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Si te fijas, hay un salto de linea al final de la URL,lo que indica que la URL no esta completamente limpia, tiene un caracter al final, por lo que te recomiendo corregir la URL usando `trim()` (o derechamente limpiar el valor en la base de datos)

```
$imagen_url = trim($_POST["imagenProductoBD"]);
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, de verdad. He utilizado el código que me adjuntas, pero me devuelve lo que pongo en la descripción de mi problema. Gracias de nuevo de verdad

Comment: por cierto uso setopt() porque vi que era para contenido https

Comment: Pude reproducir el problema cuando me di cuenta del mensaje de error. Le agregue un salto de linea `\n` al final de la URL y me dio el mismo error. Sin este funciona ok.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, de verdad!! bendito foro este!!!

Comment: Una ultima consulta, siento haber cerrado ya el tema. Como puedo controlar, si el archivo es png o jpg¿?? porque estoy probando a poner una imagen manualmente, pero claro, el formato cambia, y si no es con el que se ha guardado, falla

Comment: ya lo he resulto, el ultimo parámetro de $pdf->file() fuerzo a que fuera png, le he quitado el png y listo